# Screen sharing on Ubuntu doesn't start any vnc service - shall it?

Tags: ubuntu, vnc

I tried following many tutorials stating this is somewhat easy.

But I couldn't make this work.

Main goal: **Control Ubuntu Desktop (current desktop! NOT a new one!) from a Windows client**.

So I enabled the "Screen sharing":

[image]

However, VNC doesn't seem to be running at all:

```
# netstat -all | grep 5900
#
```

What am I missing?

My system is:

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: is `vino` installed (the program those settings control)? is the server running on a different 590X port? tightvnc defaults to 5901, not sure about ubuntu's default vino

Comment: Yes, `vino` is installed. How can I know which port is it running on?

Comment: you're specifically grepping for `5900`. looking for `590.` would give you anything in the 5900–5909 range